# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,43)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, knn, valueerror

I am using sklearn to implement KNN. I am passing an entry corresponding to one row of the database for the algorithm to sort. However, an error is returning.

Código:

```
entrada = [2.41,46.99,0.4,3,2.3,4,3.7,3,2.4,4,1983,2]   
entrada = np.array(entrada).reshape(1, (len(entrada)))
resultado = classificador.predict(entrada)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

reshape new size must be a tuple

use:

```
import numpy as np
entrada = [2.41,46.99,0.4,3,2.3,4,3.7,3,2.4,4,1983,2]   
entrada = np.array(entrada).reshape((1, len(entrada)))
print(entrada)
[[2.410e+00 4.699e+01 4.000e-01 3.000e+00 2.300e+00 4.000e+00 3.700e+00
  3.000e+00 2.400e+00 4.000e+00 1.983e+03 2.000e+00]]
```

Comment: @AmandaBeatriz exactly *what* error persists, and *where* does in come from? Maybe from the next line `classificador.predict(entrada)`? Please clarify